# Series expansion of a function $f(x,y)$ at zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x,y)$ be the function of a "complex form"

$$ f(x,y)=d(x,y)+\sqrt{d^{2}(x,y)+\dfrac{\cos^{2}x}{1+\frac{a^{2}}{c^{2}}}},$$

where

\begin{align*}
a(y) & =\frac{\pi}{2y}-\frac{2y}{\pi},\\
b(x) & =\frac{2x}{\pi},\\
c(x) & =\frac{1-b^{2}(x)}{\sin x-b(x)},\\
d(x,y) & =\dfrac{\frac{a(y)}{c(x)}\sin x-\frac{a(y)}{2}}{1+\frac{a^{2}(x)}{c^{2}(y)}}.
\end{align*}
For $x\rightarrow0$ and $y\rightarrow0$, $f(x,y)\rightarrow\pm\infty$. How to find
Taylor (or different) series at $f(0,0)$? Which type of series do
you recommend? Mathematica provides the solution of

```
a = (Pi / (2 * y) - 2 * y / Pi);
b = 2 * x / Pi
c = (1 - b^2) / (Sin[x] - b);
d = (a/c * Sin[x] - a/2) / (1 + a^2 / c^2)
f = d + Sqrt[d^2 + Cos[x]^2/(1 + a^2 / c^2)];
ft = Normal[Series[f, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]]
```

in the following form

$$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{\pi}y+-\frac{8}{\pi^{3}}x^{2}y+(\frac{96}{\pi^{5}}-\frac{32}{\pi^{4}})x^{2}y^{3}+O(4).$$

Hence, the expansion of the function at $(0, 0)$ exists, while

```
fn =  N[f /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}, 8]
```

is indeterminate... The function course for $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $y\in[-\pi,\pi]$ is

```
Plot3D[f, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ gammatester: of course, thanks, corrected.

Comment: Why do you think that $f\to\infty$ for $x\to 0$ or $y\to 0$? It doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @ yohBS: $f$ represents a simplied example; should be for $x\rightarrow0$ and $y\rightarrow0$. Sorry, my mistake, corrected.

Comment: `f /. {x -> 0.0001, y -> 0.0001}` returns 0.000063, which agrees perfectly with the `Series` expression. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @ yohBS: Of course, I could compute $f(0\pm\delta,0\pm\delta)$ (and I used it). However, the problem is how to perform the expansion at $f(0,0)$. I would like to know something more about the approach (fix the singularity or use a different type of series?)...